# How can we sort based on distance and name in ios when fetching from core data

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using Restkit to retrive an array of data from database. I want the array to be sorted based on a parameter distance in the ascending order. The problem is that if the array contains two or more entries with same distance it has to be in turn sort based on the ascending order of their names. 
I am currently using `NSSortDescriptor`

```
RKManagedObjectStore *managedObjectStore      = [[[VBRestKit sharedDataManager]objectManager] managedObjectStore];
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext  = managedObjectStore.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext;

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest        = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity         = [NSEntityDescription
                                       entityForName:@"VBDeals" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
NSSortDescriptor *sortById = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"distance" ascending:YES];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortById]];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSError *error;
NSArray *fetchedObjects             = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];


VBResponseWrapper *responseWrapper = [[VBResponseWrapper alloc]init];

responseWrapper.responseObject = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:fetchedObjects];

return responseWrapper;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add another sort descriptor:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortById = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"distance" ascending:YES];
NSSortDescriptor *sortByName = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortById, sortByName, nil]];
```

Just make sure you change the key (name) to match your data.
Hope this help.

Comment: I tried this but the whole sorting changed to name based an there is no distance based sorting. I want only the same distance items to be sorted based on name.

Comment: It should works for you, maybe you need to amend key, for example object.name. You can always subclass NSSortDescriptor and override the compareObject:toObject: to compare the distance first and dame second.

Comment: Finally it worked for me. The problem was that i didnt add caseinsensitive to the sort descriptor.
here is the code
NSSortDescriptor *sortById = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"distance" ascending:YES];
NSSortDescriptor *sortByName = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortById, sortByName, nil]];